# XGBOOST with target column has categorical data and features also has categorical data

Tags: xgboost, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I have a huge dataset with the categorical columns in features and also my target variable is categorical.

All the values are not ordinal so I think it is best to use one hot encoding.

But I have one issue that my target variable have 90 classes so if I do one hot encoding there will be 90 columns as the target columns and it will become to much complex.

But as all the values are not ordinal can I apply one hot encoding for the features categorical columns and label encoder for the target variable?

Thanks

Comment: BTW, if your data contains a lot of categorical features, worth to try [CatBoost](https://catboost.ai/).

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a classic case of high dimensional categorical data. Basically you have a lot of categorical features in your input, along with the target variable having a lot of classes.

In this case I would suggest not using `OneHotEncoder` as it will further increase your dimensionality and result in poor predictions.

Also you mentioned that there are no ordinal features. Hence using `OrdinalEncoder` won't make sense too.

There are a lot of different types of encoders, not just OneHot and Ordinal and depending on your type of features, you can choose which one suits the best. [category-encoders](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/) has a list of various encoders you can check out.

I would suggest `CatBoostEncoder` or `LeaveOneOutEncoder` as they usually perform best on high dimensional data but try out all and see which works.

**Cheers!**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your dataset and your target. From my experience I can say that it is possible. In some case I applied label encoding to a categorical classes and hot encoding to the features of the dataset.

You could provide an example of your dataset and explain your target if you want a specific answer.

Comment: Sure I will show update my database